# Find out how much all tmp directy occupy

Tags: disk-usage

How can I know the size of all tmp folders for all users.

I tried

```
du -h /home/*/tmp
```

But it did not add them all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have GNU `du`, the `-c` flag should do what you want.

```
$ du -hcs /home/*/tmp

[...]

3.9M total
```

You can trim to the final total by using `tail`:

```
$ du -hcs /home/*/tmp | tail -1
```

Comment: Seems wasteful to list all sub dirs and then trim, should use `du -hcs /home/*/tmp | tail -1`

Comment: @user2354329 `-s` makes no difference in the output when using `tail` afterwards, and realistically makes no difference in the speed of execution. You will spend more time typing `s` than the time it will save.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly your question is about.

Maybe you simply want:

```
du -hs /home/*/tmp
```

Comment: Yeah, but it does not add them all together.

Answer (score 0):

If you **just** want the total amount the easiest is probably:

```
du -shc | tail -1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple command

```
 du -sh /tmp
```

Comment: Although there might be user data there as well, this does not add up the amounts in the directories indicated by the OP.